# ListFragment with different Layout

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I am working on Fragment-ListView and having output showing in image.
every Click changes TextView of fragment2.till now ok.

fragmetn1 is for listView and fragment2 is for DifferentView.

now i want to change layout in fragment2 with click. e.g. as item2 is clicked,a layout with textView sets in fragment2. now with selection of item3, diferent layout with Button should be set to fragment2.

my getView code is here.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);

        if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
            frag.setText("item "+position+" selected");
        }
    }
```

**is there other way to do this,plz also help that way.**

any suggestion would be strongly appreciated.thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

then you need to add your fragment to this fragmentTransaction with the following syntax.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, layout1);
```

And finally you MUST commit your transaction. Otherwise changes will not persist.

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use different fragments with different layout and using FragmentTransaction to replace the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach likely works fine, but it is probably better to use a more loosely coupled approach where the ListFragment informs the hosting activity that an item has been clicked, and then the activity tells the "other" fragment to update.

No need to worry about constructing and replacing new fragments.

**Sample activity**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements TestFragmentBListener {
    private TestFragmentA mOtherFragment;
    private TestFragmentB mListFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        mListFrag = (TestFragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b_list);
        mOtherFragment = (TestFragmentA) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_a_text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFragmentBItemCLicked(int position) {
        // Implemented from TestFragmentB.TestFragmentBListener
        mOtherFragment.setText("item " + position + " selected.");
    }
}
```

**Sample FragmentA (contains text.. this is not functional, only an example)**

```
public class TestFragmentA extends Fragment {
    public void setText(String text) {
    }
}
```

**Sample ListFragment that defines an interface for the sample activity to implement**

```
public class TestFragmentB extends ListFragment {
    private TestFragmentBListener mListener = null;

    public interface TestFragmentBListener {
        void onTestFragmentBItemCLicked(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (TestFragmentBListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException ccex) {
            // activity does not implement our listener
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onTestFragmentBItemCLicked(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**and for the sake of completeness, here was my layout for the sample activity:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_b_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_a_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```